# Why am I experiencing an infinite loop here?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

My code never stops asking for input so I think I must've made an infinite loop, but I can't find where the error is. I've also noticed that when inserting the input line by line, it prints the result of one loop after inserting the first line of the second loop, which seems incorrect to me. Please help me debug. (For further context, the code is supposed to receive a number we'll call n, and then scan 3n more lines, which are basically n bundles of 3 similar lines. The 2nd and 3rd lines are two words with the same num of characters, and the 1st line is that num. The output is whether or not these words are anagrams.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, l;

    scanf("%d\n", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d\n", &l);
        char A[l], B[l];

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            scanf("%c", &A[j]);
            scanf("\n");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            scanf("%c", &B[j]);
            scanf("\n");
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            int result = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                if (A[k] == B[j]) {
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
            if (!result) {
                printf("\nNO\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\nYES\n");
    }
}
```

Example:

input:

```
2
6
listen
silent
4
Evil
live
```

output:

```
YES
NO
```

Comment: could you post an example of the input?

Comment: Do you enter each letter of `evil`, `live` etc. on a separate line or do you only press enter after the whole word?

Comment: Do you regard  `abbbbbb` and `aaaaaab` to be "consisting of same letters"?

Comment: @Gerhardh count each space as a line break, so each word is on one line not each character. And no, the words must be anagrams. It's also case-sensitive, hence why the second example receives "NO" as its output.

Comment: Why are there 2 different numbers before listen and silent, I thought it’s 1 number followed by 2 words?

Comment: Oh the first number tells it to scan 2x3 next lines ?

Comment: @anarchy first is `n` which is the number of test cases. Then the length `l` of the first 2 words

Comment: So the second case is no because the e is capitalised correct ?

Comment: Ok give me a bit I’ll try it out

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are asking for input over and over and over again,

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but start by removing the extra `scanf`s

try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, l;

    scanf("%d\n", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        char A[l], B[l];


        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            int result = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                if (A[k] == B[j]) {
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
            if (!result) {
                printf("\nNO\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\nYES\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the other 2 scanfs to receive two words as arrays. The point of the code is to compare those two words to see if they are made up of the same set of letters. Based on my debugger, I don't think the code has a problem receiving the words, the arrays are correct and so is the result, until the last set. This is why I think something is wrong with my loop?

Comment: @Maya could you post an example of the input?

Comment: You removed all the input for `A` and `B` That causes undefined behaviour when you compare uninitialized variables

Comment: @anarchy I've added it to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` calls wait for an extra `\n` which requires more input to enter.

To fix this, remove the `\n` from your `scanf` calls. Also remove the extra calls when you enter  `A` and `B`:

I have added some debug code to demonstrate where you are in your program execution while you enter your input.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, l;
    int res;

    res=scanf("%d", &n);

printf ("res=%d, n=%d\n", res, n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        res = scanf("%d", &l);

printf ("res=%d, l=%d\n", res, l);

//        char A[l], B[l];
        char A[l+1], B[l+1];

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            scanf(" %c", &A[j]);
        }      

printf ("A done\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            scanf(" %c", &B[j]);
        }

printf ("B done\n");

A[l] = 0; B[l] = 0;
printf ("A=\"%s\" - B=\"%s\"\n", A, B);
...
```

Now your input should work properly.

But your code also contains another error.
You will treat `"12344"` and `"11234"` as correct match wchich is wrong.

To fix this you need to remove each matching character from `B`:

```c
        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            int result = 0;

// We compare A[k] with the remaining characters in B only
            for (int j = k; j < l; j++) {
                if (A[k] == B[j]) {
                    result = 1;
                    B[j] = B[k]; // Replace matching character with non-matching character we checked earlier.
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!result) {
                printf("\nNO\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\nYES\n");
```

This code stops as soon as the first match is found and removed that character from `B`.
The entries in `B` are rearranged to keep the unused entries at the end.

The full code looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, l;
    int res;

    res=scanf("%d", &n);

printf ("res=%d, n=%d\n", res, n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        res = scanf("%d", &l);

printf ("res=%d, l=%d\n", res, l);

//        char A[l], B[l];
        char A[l+1], B[l+1];

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            scanf(" %c", &A[j]);
        }      

printf ("A done\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            scanf(" %c", &B[j]);
        }

printf ("B done\n");

A[l] = 0; B[l] = 0;
printf ("A=\"%s\" - B=\"%s\"\n", A, B);
        

        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            int result = 0;
            for (int j = k; j < l; j++) {
                if (A[k] == B[j]) {
                    result = 1;
                    B[j] = B[k];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!result) {
                printf("\nNO\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\nYES\n");
    }
}
```

output:

```
~/stackoverflow$ ./test
4
res=1, n=4
2
res=1, l=2
12
A done
21
B done
A="12" - B="21"

YES
6
res=1, l=6
liver1
A done
evil1r
B done
A="liver1" - B="evil1r"

YES
3
res=1, l=3
111
A done
111
B done
A="111" - B="111"

YES
4
res=1, l=4
abcd
A done
dcbb
B done
A="abcd" - B="dcbb"

NO
```

Comment: Thank you, although when I removed the \n scanners completely, every \n became an array character, so I added an if condition for the last \n instead. Now it gives the output after one extra \n which is fine I think. Apparently I have a whole other problem elsewhere tho. Just gave it a bigger n (n = 4) and it still gave me only 2 outputs instead of 4. Any idea why?

Comment: My version also works for n=4. See update.

Comment: That's odd, 'cause I just copy pasted your exact code and despite the fact that it did give 4 outputs for my input, they were wrong and none of the other stuff you'd assigned for it to print printed. Thank you so much for your help though, hopefully I'll figure out this bit.

Comment: That sounds as if you compiled something else...